# Open iis from run but getting error in window xp

Tags: asp.net, iis, iis-7, iis-6

You can see the iis configuration and error message in the image.Service pack 3 is installed on the system.
[image]

Comment: What version of XP are you running? You need to be running XP Pro if I remember correctly.

Comment: As much i know it doesn't depends on the OS type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to be running XP Pro to install IIS. It does not come with XP Home Edition:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb763170.aspx

If you are running XP Pro, then the correct version of IIS should be 5.1

Comment: It means i need to reinstall my window :(

Comment: Maybe not: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-NZ/itproxpsp/thread/79551f13-ffdd-42bb-b753-2c209eb8e1e5